# Jquery.ajax() enquiry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to ask if i want to use Jquery Ajax to get a numeric value from a website, any ideas on how to start?

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank-you!

Regards,

SWIFT

Comment: Do you have a website that prints a numeric value?  Is it the same domain as what's serving the ajax?

Comment: It is more of a website from the local host. It displays numbers of packets recieved. And i want to get the value of it.

Comment: `$.ajax('/path/to/page/that/prints/numbers')` is no good?

Comment: I have to create a new .js javascript file with $.ajax('/path/to/page/that/prints/numbers') in it?

Comment: Something like that.  `$.ajax(url).done(function (number) { alert(number); });`

Comment: You have to have some file to read. If it's a service (php, etc) that prints a number or html or plain text it's all ok. Ajax just gets that file. You do need to have a url where you can see the number you're trying to display.

Comment: Oh Okay. Then how do i test it ? Sorry i am quite new to ajax. >_<

Comment: So do i create a new html file to see the result ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
$.get("/yoururl", function (numberString) {
    var i = parseInt(numberString);
    alert(i);
});
```

Comment: Then how do i display this 'i' value ?

Comment: The `alert` function will display it for you in a pop-up box. If you need to know how to put it into a div look at the documentation on jQuery's website - specifically for functions like `append()`, `text()`, `html()`.